# is mknod portable? if not, what is the alternative?

Tags: c, posix, mknod

I would like to use `mknod` in my code to create a file, but `man` says, that

> The only portable use of mknod() is to create a FIFO-special file.  If mode is not S_IFIFO or dev is not  0,  the  behavior  of
>          mknod()  is unspecified.

Does that mean, that mknod is not really portable and I should use some other way to create a function? How about calling `open` and the instantly `close`? Which way is safer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mknod` is not for creating files. It's for creating *device nodes*. A portable application will never need to create device nodes because whether they exist, what they are, and how they're implemented/numbered is an *implementation detail*.

`mknod` historically allowed you to create fifos too (and perhaps ordinary files?), but there are instead standard interfaces for this: `mkfifo` for fifos, and `creat` (or `open` with `O_CREAT`) for ordinary files.

Comment: Still, I need to open and then close the returned descriptor, which requires two operations (and four damn lines, since I am always checking the return codes). So there is no single operation for creating a file?

Comment: I generally consider checking the return value of `close` useless. If you pass it a valid file descriptor, the only way `close` can fail is if you've installed an interrupting signal handler (which I consider harmful, aside from very isolated and intentional usage) or on I/O errors (e.g. with NFS). And since there's really no good way of recovering from the latter, I follow the principle of "never test for an error you don't know how to handle". :-)

Comment: Oh, but to answer your question, no, there is no single library call to create a file. Are you really sure you'd want to create a file without having it open? Usually you want to use `O_EXCL` when creating new files to ensure that you really were the one to create it, and if you close and later reopen the file, the whole point of `O_EXCL` is defeated.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the rest of that paragraph, you will see:

```
However, nowadays one should never use mknod() for this purpose;
one should use mkfifo(3), a function especially defined for this purpose.
```

so what `POSIX.1-2001`says here is already outdated. I would just ignore it. `mknod`is still being used by the init scripts in the Linux systems.

Comment: In a linux init script, mknod is being used for an appropriate implementation-specific purpose, ie making a device node.

Comment: I have assumed the author was asking for creating a device node :)

Comment: OP seems to be using it to create ordinary files. In all my years of unix coding, I had no idea there were implementations of `mknod` that could even do this, and it sounds like a really horrible abuse of the function...